# How many non negative integer solutions does the inequality x+y+z+t<15 have?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I attempted this problem in many ways, but all of them were wrong. I started off using the stars and bars method, which I used to solve my previous problem.

1. I had a total of fourteen stars as the solution contains integers less than 14. I put in three bars as I could divide the stars into 4 groups. Then I added the stars and bars (17) and did 17 choose 3 getting 680. This was my first attempt
2. I attempted to count the solutions but I realized this was too tedious and moved on
3. I realized my stars and bars were only for the number 14 and not 13, 12, 11, 10 and so on so I added the stars and bars
   And I got 3050 which is completely wrong.

I just don't know where to go and what theorem to use, an answer would be nice but any guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: Perhaps it is easiest to add a new non-negative variable $w=14-x-y-z-t$ and look at $x+y+z+t+w=14$.  Then a routine application of Stars and Bars gives $\binom {14+5-1}{5-1}=3060$.

Comment: Note:  your method $\#3$ should have worked...$\sum_{n=0}^{14}\binom {n+4-1}{4-1}=3060$ as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion on the comments:

Your third method certainly should have worked, but you appear to have made an arithmetic error somewhere.  We have $$\sum_{n=0}^{14}\binom {n+4-1}{4-1}=3060$$

not $3050$ as you claim.

A quicker method:  define a new non-negative variable $$w=14-x-y-z-t$$ and now consider the equality $$x+y+z+t+w=14$$

A routine application of Stars and Bars yields $$\binom {14-5-1}{5-1}=3060$$ as before.